# laravel 5.4 redis server ddos attack

Tags: php, node.js, laravel-5, redis, phpredis

I setup Laravel 5.4 app with redis server. I got some ddos attack on my server 
and I got my redis server cache unknown info,
like `some-email|some-ip`.

here's a screenshot :

[image]

I changed the old port and set `require password`. And I also changed redis folder permissions. But still I am getting this error.

My server is ubuntu 16 with nginx, node.js, php7 and redis server(phpredis).

How to secure my server from ddos attack?

Answer (score 0):

I like putting my sites through cloudflare.com. It protects from DDOS, and also caches assets like CSS and JS, speeding up your site.

Also, you can use a self signed SSL certificate, but because of Cloudflare you will get the full green padlock! :-)

Comment: I used cloudflare.com and laravel mix for caching assets.
But the attack is very huge.

Comment: oh wow, this is happening WITH Cloudflare? Isn't there an emergency button you can hit? I think I saw that somewhere

Comment: i also choice i'm under attack but still get huge attack.
i need something help with redis server.

Comment: Is it only your own site connecting to redis? Can't you limit it to accepting connections from 127.0.0.1 only?

Comment: yes, i changed the redis.conf to  bind 127.0.0.1 but still cache unknown info from outside.
there is another away?

Comment: Can't really help much more than that amigo, sorry, but good luck!